# Angular Ngrx store.reduce is not a function

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to implement Ngrx with Angular's standalone API like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { CartItem, Product } from '../types';
import { Observable, map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';


@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatChipsModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgIf,
    NgFor,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  selector: 'app-display',
  templateUrl: './display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display.component.css'],
})
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  products?: Product[];
  cart$: Observable<CartItem[]>;
  cartSize$: Observable<number>;
  

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private store: Store<{ cart: CartItem[] }>
  ) {
    this.cart$ = this.store.select('cart');
    this.cartSize$ = this.store.select('cart').pipe(
      map((products: CartItem[]) =>
        products.reduce((total, { quantity }) => total + quantity, 0)
      ),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.dataService
      .getData()
      .subscribe((products) => (this.products = products));
  }

}
```

with the following actions:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { CartItem, Product } from 'src/app/types';

export const addItem = createAction(
  '[Cart Page] Add Item',
  props<{ item: CartItem }>()
);
export const removeItem = createAction(
  '[Cart Page] Remove Item',
  props<{ productId: number }>()
);
export const updateItem = createAction(
  '[Cart Page] Edit Item',
  props<{ productId: number; quantity: number }>()
);
```

and reducer:

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { CartItem, Product } from 'src/app/types';
import { addItem, removeItem, updateItem } from './cart.actions';

export interface CartState {
  cart: CartItem[];
  error: string | null;
  status: 'pending' | 'loading' | 'error' | 'success';
}

export const initialState: CartState = {
  cart: [],
  error: null,
  status: 'pending',
};

export const cartReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addItem, (state, { item }) => ({
    ...state,
    cart: [...state.cart, { ...item }],
  })),
  on(removeItem, (state, { productId }) => ({
    ...state,
    cart: state.cart.filter((_item) => _item.id !== productId),
  })),
  on(updateItem, (state, { productId, quantity }) => {
    const updatedCart = state.cart.map((_item) => {
      if (_item.id === productId) {
        return { ..._item, quantity };
      } else {
        return _item;
      }
    });
    return {
      ...state,
      cart: updatedCart,
    };
  })
);
```

and this is my main.ts file:

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { StoreModule, provideStore } from '@ngrx/store';
import { cartReducer } from './app/state/cart/cart.reducer';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      HttpClientModule,
      StoreModule.forRoot({ cart: cartReducer })
    ),
  ],
});
```

But I'm getting this error in the following code:

```
this.cartSize$ = this.store.select('cart').pipe(
  map((products: CartItem[]) =>
    products.reduce((total, { quantity }) => total + quantity, 0)
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

and the error reads:

```
ERROR TypeError: products.reduce is not a function
```

and I'm calling the cartSize$ value in the html like so:

```
<h1>{{cartSize$ | async}}</h1>
```

There is no value printing, not even 0, so I'm assuming it's undefined although I'm not sure as to why it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array,

```
 products?: Product[] = [];
```

Comment: 'products.reduce((total, { quantity }) => total + quantity, 0)' isn't referring to the var I created but the return value of map operator

Comment: do you have objects within the array

Comment: Yes of type CartItem: {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  image: string;
  quantity: number;
}

Comment: I am asking valid objects, you can print the length before applying reduce

Comment: The length is undefined, just checked

Comment: which means the objects are not getting assigned, which results in the error

Answer (score 0):

The error message "products.reduce is not a function" is occurring in the following code:

```
this.cartSize$ = this.store.select('cart').pipe(
 map((products: CartItem[]) =>
  products.reduce((total, { quantity }) => total + quantity, 0)
 ), shareReplay(1));
```

This error message indicates that the reduce function is not available in the product array.
This could be because products are undefined or not an array.

*One possible reason for this is that the cart property in the store is not initialized properly.*

To fix this issue, you can modify the reducer to initialize the cart property to an empty array:

```
export const initialState: CartState = {
 cart: [], // initialize cart to an empty array
 error: null,
 status: 'pending'
};
```

Alternatively, you can modify the cartSize$ observable to handle the case where products is undefined:

```
this.cartSize$ = this.store.select('cart').pipe(
map((products: CartItem[]) =>
 products ? products.reduce((total, { quantity }) => total + quantity, 0) : 0
), shareReplay(1));
```

This will set the cart size to 0 if products is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array of products in order to use `reduce()` function.

```
products = new Array<Products>();
```

> Read more about `Array.prototype.reduce()` [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)